# Different different version of same code

Tags: c++, macros

I developed a small soft, that just uploads files to one provider. The provider can be set before compilation.

Actually I have three same projects (with same code) but with three different provider. To illustrate, I have copied two times the folder project and modified only the source code relative to the provider.

I search a solution to join to the same project and just set a "variable" to choose the provider at the compilation

I thought to create a #define PROVIDER, with provider = [ S3 | YOUTUBE | FTP ], and then to write in code

```
#ifdef S3
provider = new S3Provider();
#elif YOUTUBE
provider = new YoutubeProvider();
#else
provider = new FtpProvider();
#endif
```

This solution is a bit ugly and I don't know other ways

Can you help me please ?
Thank you !

Comment: Is it acceptable to have all providers in code and then choose one in run time?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `#ifndef` and not `#ifdef`? Or rather, if you're checking the `PROVIDER` macro, shouldn't it be more like  `#if PROVIDER == S3`?

Comment: As for your actual question, I would say it's a matter of style and personal preference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You can't do string comparison in `#if`; `==` only works for integers.

Comment: @ams It all depends on *what* `S3` etc. is. Is it macros defined to numbers? Just defined (but empty) macros? Something else? Unfortunately the OP doesn't tell us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think it would have to be a macro defined to a number, but defining PROVIDER would then have to allow for multiple levels of substitution, and you're into *hidden magic*, which is bad. Of course, this *is* a C++ question, so maybe it's the least bad thing in the code?

Comment: Some pure unbridled dogmatism: unless you want an unmanageable plethora of build configurations, adopt a scheme where the selection is made at *runtime*. Pretty please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want conditional compilation then preprocessor defines *are* the way to do it, although you can pass the values in on the command line instead of writing it into the source.

```
#if defined(USE_S3)
provider = new S3Provider();
#elif defined(USE_YOUTUBE)
provider = new YoutubeProvider();
#elif defined(USE_FTP)
provider = new FtpProvider();
#else
#error You must specify a provider!
#endif
```

And compile with

```
c++ -DUSE_S3 blah.cc
```

Note that you *can't* use `-DPROVIDER=S3` because `#if` does not allow string comparison.

---

An alternative solution is to name the provider class on the command line:

```
#ifndef PROVIDER
#error You must specify a provider!
#endif

provider = new PROVIDER ();  // The space before () is important!
```

and then compile with

```
c++ -DPROVIDER=S3Provider
```

I prefer the first one because it better documents that three providers are implemented.

Comment: it is possible to do g++ -DUSE_S3 -DUSE_YOUTUBE -DUSE_FTP  which now depends in the order of options evaluation...

Comment: so actually this answer reiterates the OP answer and tells to just use c++ -DUSE_FTP ... omg that was simple!

Comment: @g24l Yes, it's possible to screw up programming; who knew? ;-) And yes, I think the OP's solution was basically the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, the second solution works very well and is "pretty"

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way that you want to do it is by using `typedef`

```
typedef PROVIDER_TYPE provider_type;

provider =  new provider_type();
```

compile with `g++ -DPROVIDER_TYPE=S3` to get `S3`

Now, you cannot get non-sensical case as `g++ -DPROVIDER_TYPE=x -DPROVIDER_TYPE=y` because you will get very nice pre-processor errors.

Even better you can put that in a header file and completely drop the base class provider because you could do:

```
provider_type * provider = new provider_type();
```

Comment: Unlike other solutions there is no need for space before () , or anywhere else in the code as the typedef behaves just as a normal construct.

Answer (score 1):

You might use some *configuration* file (perhaps located in a well defined place by default, like `~/.myprogconf` on Linux) and have your program parse it and use some generic (HTTP & FTP client) library (such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) later.